# Custom environment-based extensions in vite

Tags: plugins, config, vite

I have a React project in Vite, and I want to be able to have custom environment-based extensions, e.g. `.foo.ts` and `.bar.ts` where the `foo` and `bar` versions of the files should be used depending on the existence of an environment variable, e.g. `CUSOMER=foo`, and the default extension (bare `.ts`) is used for all others.

What is the best way to configure this?

I've tried creating a custom resolver in vite, and tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-alias but I can't quite get the hang of it.